# Cannot install MvvmCross in VS2013

Tags: c#, android, windows, mono, mvvmcross

I am running Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio Professional 2013 including Update 1.

I want to write apps which can be deployed to Windows Phone, Windows 8, Windows 7, and Android.

Here is a great tutorial on what I want to do
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&list=PLR6WI6W1JdeYSXLbm58jwAKYT7RQR31-W&v=_DHDMNB_IeY&t=107s
but right at the start when the Portable class library is created the presenter has the option on the 'Add Portable Class Library' window where you can select the target frameworks, the video has "Mono for Android' but I do not have the option.

I assume that I need to install it through Extensions and Updates.  It finds the 'Ninja Coder for MvvmCross' by Adrian Sudbury.  It prompts me to download, I follow the link, download and run the msi, it successfully installs, then restart VS2013 but the MvvmCross does not appear in the list of installed packages.

Reading the link 
    http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.All/
I need to type on the PM> console
        Install-Package MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.All
this does stuff and returns 
    .... 
    Successfully added 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.All 3.1.1' to TestApp.

Then if I try and create a new PCL then I still do not have the option of 'Mono for Android'

How do I create a project that can be deployed to Windows Phone, Windows 8, Windows 7, and Android.

Comment: Needed to install Xamarin